# How to Select MAX column value from fetched SQL rows

Tags: max, fetch, sql-server-2014

I have SQL to get 5 rows... how do I get the max value from this fetch. for example I want 1990.75.
here are the results of the fetch
1990.25
1990.50
1990.00
1900.00
1990.75
Or if there is a better way? I need to get the last 5 records which are already sorted by date DESC and time DESC in the table (the 5 may change to another number)

```
    DECLARE @CurrentSetNumber int = 0;
DECLARE @NumRowsInSet int = 5;

SELECT [Stock_High]
FROM [dbo].[HistData]
Where BarSize = '5 mins'
Order by RecordID   

OFFSET @NumRowsInSet * @CurrentSetNumber ROWS
FETCH NEXT @NumRowsInSet ROWS ONLY;

SET @CurrentSetNumber = @CurrentSetNumber + 1;
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The 5 rows/values that you have after sorting, stores those 5 values into a table variable or temp table and then get max of values from temp table.